# Inserting Session variables into a form via PHP

Tags: php, forms, session-variables

I am trying to insert a Session Variable  $_SESSION['MM_loginName'] into a table via a form.

I know the Session Variable works on the new page by using:

```
<?php
 echo "MM_loginName = {$_SESSION['MM_loginName']} <br>\n";
?>
```

I have read that this might work (if register globals is off):

```
<input type="hidden" name="loginName" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["MM_loginName"]; ?>" />
```

but it doesn't, because I think register globals has been DEPRECATED.

This is supposed to work:

```
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo "$myusername"; ?>" />
```

but i  don't know how to rewrite the code to "$loginName"

Help,

Here is my table/form structure:

```
<tr>
   <td width="99"></td>
   <td width="391"><input type="hidden" name="loginName" id="loginName" value= "????/></td>
</tr>
```

Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your first one isn't working because references to array variable values within strings aren't evaluated within `echo` statements. Assuming that you want to put the username, which is stored in the session, into the value field of your form, I would do something like:

```
<tr>
   <td width="99"></td>
   <td width="391"><input type="hidden" name="loginName" id="loginName" value= "<?php echo $_SESSION['MM_loginName']; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Winnner Winner Chicken Dinner!!!!   Thanks that worked perfectly...Thanks a bazillion..michael

Answer (score 0):

If the first code fragment works, there is no logical reason for the second not to work. They are exactly the same thing from a PHP perspective.

You do have to register the session before any calls to the session global, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php

Comment: Sorry, they both don't work, Do you know how to turn the $_SESSION["MM_loginName"] into $myloginName  ?